# How to re-install / re-activate the AMD open source drivers (the ones which come with a fresh install)

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, opencl

Problem: I installed the ROCm drivers because I wanted to use OpenCL. But I did not remove them before upgrading those drivers. So, ever since the ROGm drivers updated automatically, they are broken. So I decided to uninstall ROCm completely. Well, that didn't work: DKMS-issues. And after that: max and only resolution 1024 x 768.

Sigh. Everything I know from the past doesn't seem to work. Tried re-installing de rock-dkms and rocm-dkms, also in the previous kernel. Etc. etc.

When I remove my AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT and use the onboard Intel video card, everything is back to normal, but I do have an extra video card for a reason ;)

So, is there any way to get back to the former normal regular open source drivers which come included with Ubuntu?

ps, I would love to paste error messages, but I wouldn't know where to start after so many tries.

pps, again: I should learn never to install any AMD stuff again.

Edit: first of all I should have checked the [issues](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues) on GitHub, never thought of it. Doing it now, see many similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have `amdgpu` in your kernel modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep amd
amdgpu 4575232 11
amd_iommu_v2 20480 1 amdgpu
gpu_sched 32768 1 amdgpu
ttm 106496 1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper 184320 1 amdgpu
drm 487424 7 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
i2c_algo_bit 16384 1 amdgpu
```

If not, check that the module is not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf`. If it is, but comment out or delete the file.

After that perform a reboot.

Comment: On Ubunrtu 20.04.2 LTS. Tried updating to new amdgpu-pro 20.45 and got a fail on dkms and dependencies when installing. After several uninstall / reinstall strategies the best I got was a low res screen with sudo lshw -c video reporting display unclaimed and no driver in configuration: .I noticed the blacklist so tried this and now have amdgpu driver. THANKS. 
Just need to figure out what else I've screwed up in the last  couple of days of messing around.

less /et

Comment: **commands** `less /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf`
`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf`